# iOS Keyboard Weirdness "Can't find keyplane"

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, uikeyboardtype

I'm getting this message in the console when simply trying to have a UITextField with the decimal keyboard

```
Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 1425143906_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
```

This happens on both iOS8 and iOS7.

Also the keyboard just looks really weird, namely the half boarder around the decimal button. I believe in iOS6 and older, the decimal button used to take up the entire space but it looks like thats not the case anymore. Also if I tap the empty space to the left of it, the decimal button is still pressed.

(Decimal not being pressed)

[image]

(Decimal being pressed and held)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the simulators Hardware menu -> 
1. Ensure that "Connect Hardware Keyboard" is selected. 
2. Then click on "Toggle software keyboard"